# In android is there any direct method that executes a query and returns a cursor?

Tags: android

In android is there any direct method that executes a query and returns a cursor??

like in java there is statement.getCursor()
is there any equivalent method in android?

Answer (score 2):

you can execute query this way

```
Cursor cursor;

String select = "Select * from contactTable";

try {

  cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery(select, null);

  for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
    cursor.moveToNext();
    // your code
  }      
  cursor.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}finally{
        myDataBase.close();
        SQLiteDatabase.releaseMemory();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I find the best way to interface with a database in android is to use a DatabaseAdapter class.
This is a class loaded up with methods that do everything you could want to do with a database. Some good reading on this can be found [here](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40842). Just check out listing 4.

Also, make sure to use an SQLiteOpenHelper in conjunction with your database adapter. This will create a database automatically if one doesnt exist, and handle upgrades automatically as well. Be careful though: SQLiteOpenHelper will only help you create one table per database automatically, I get around this by just creating multiple databases. As SQLite doesn't support foreign keys I don't really see a disadvantage to this. Check out the example code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548533/full-android-database-helper-class-for-existing-sqlite-database) for SQLiteOpenHelper.