# Android database is crashing on initial run

Tags: android, database

I am using a Sqlite database, and it crashes but only the first time it is run after it installs.
It is based off of [Biff MaGriff's post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548533/full-android-database-helper-class-for-existing-sqlite-database)

It crashes right when I am trying to create the db, giving me a FileNotFoundException, so it has got to be the copyDataBase() portion

```
 InputStream myInput = dbhContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
```

However, after it crashes, I just open it up and the database is there and running, I just don't understand why it crashes while it creates the db.

Comment: Did you look at the backtrace in the DDMS perspective? It has the exact line number.

Comment: if you mean the log, I added     Log.e("whatsgoingon",error.toString());     which gives the FileNotFoundException

Comment: Try passing the exception itself as well, the Log methods accept throwables. Or use getStackTraceString if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

You're using SqlLiteOpenHelper to help with the difference between "create" and "reopen", aren't you?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html

Comment: Yes, my class extends SqlLiteOpenHelper passing the context to open or create it

Answer (score 0):

I was using a class that was intended for using a database already created and copied over, so since I didn't need that and only needed one created on first use, I used the helper class off of  http://www.screaming-penguin.com/node/7742.