# SQLite database for Android App

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, import

I have a question about databases in Android. I want to use a database in my app but I dont want to create it there. My question is now, is there a way to create a SQLite database with a specific programm on PC or is it even possible to convert an Access database into a SQLite database and then import it into my app? It will be a "static" database and the app will only have to read it.
Thanks for your help

Comment: look at here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548533/full-android-database-helper-class-for-existing-sqlite-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SQlite3 database as an internal storage in android.For that you can use SQLite3 Manager.You can get it here http://sqlitemanager.en.softonic.com/. You have to extend SQLiteOpenHelper class to use it.For more detail to use database in android please refer this link http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/.

Answer (score 0):

First create your database (with any tools for SQLite), put it in your `assets` directory, and on first use copy to `/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE/databases/` directory. then use this path to connect your database. 
See [`android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) that will access a database given a file path.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(yourDbPath, null, 0);
```

See [Using your own SQLite database in Android applications](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/).