# how to query another android device's databases through sockets (multiple devices)

Tags: android, database, sockets, serversocket

I'm generally new to android programming, though I have yet to see an answer to this question: I am well aware of the necessities of creating a connection between two or more android devices with the use of wi-fi. In terms of the serversocket and serverclient, I was curious if anybody could hint me towards how to access and query an sqlite database within android devices to communicate both two and from databases within each device. Also as for the server side, if I wanted it to be able to communicate back to a client's database, how would I go about doing so?

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Database/extendsSQLiteOpenHelper.htm) and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548533/full-android-database-helper-class-for-existing-sqlite-database) for data base.

And for communication with server from android device better use Restful webservice with JSON as data.
[this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)
 [this](http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-parse-read-json-data-into-a-android-listview/)
May be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197335/restful-api-service) will help you. Also [this](http://www.josecgomez.com/2010/04/30/android-accessing-restfull-web-services-using-json/)